# Can't convert str-casted byte-literal back to str

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a byte-literal, and I cast it to a string:

```
hi = str(b'h\ni')
```

No issues.  It is type `str`:

```
print(type(hi))        # <class 'str'>
```

When I print it, it prints as a byte-literal.  This is odd to me, because I thought I cast the byte-literal to a string:

```
print(hi)              # b'hi'
```

If I cast it to a string, so I should be able to split on `\n`:

```
print(hi.split("\n"))  # ["b'h\\ni'"]
```

This is odd, I would expect `print(hi.split("\n"))` to return a list containing the string `h` and the string `i`.

Is it possible to get `hi` back into a normal, printable, splittable string, after it has been cast to a string?

Comment: btw `casting` is not a thing in python. Converting is, however.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`str` gets a friendly human readable representation of an object. In your case, its a readable form of a `bytes` object. You want to decode instead

```
>>> hi = b'h\ni'.decode('ascii')
>>> hi
'h\ni'
>>> type(hi)
<class 'str'>
```

Comment: Thanks, yeah, this was the root of the problem.  I'm still curious how you recover from the error if you don't have the luxury of changing the initial `str()` conversion - for instance if `str(b'h\ni'.decode())` is not an option.

Comment: Barring problems with non-ascii characters that really do need a decode, you could do `hi = hi[2:-2]` to strip of the junk.

Comment: Makes sense - but ouch.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Your first line is the wrong step. You need to decode the `bytes` to `str`:

```
bi = b'h\ni'

sbi = bi.decode()

print(sbi, len(sbi))

print(sbi.split("\n"))
```

Output:

```
h
i 3
['h', 'i']
```